# How can I select the set of rows where each item has the greatest timestamp?

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

Using Sqlite, I'd like to fetch the collection of rows each with the greatest timestamp. The table contains the properties of items, which are key-value pairs and timestamp. I'd like to select the most recent value for each property.

Consider the following simplified schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Properties (thing VARCHAR,
                         key VARCHAR,
                         value VARCHAR,
                         timestamp INT);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("apple", "color", "red", 0);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("apple", "taste", "sweet", 0);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("apple", "size", "small", 0);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("watermelon", "taste", "sweet", 0);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("watermelon", "size", "large", 0);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("watermelon", "color", "pink", 1);
INSERT INTO Properties VALUES ("watermelon", "color", "green", 0);
```

I'd like to write a query for `thing="watermelon"` that returns:

```
taste|sweet
size|large
color|pink
```

Note that there are two rows with `key="color"`, and the query returns the row with the greatest `timestamp` value. Also, the greatest `timestamp` for one property may be different from another property.

*What I've tried so far includes:*

Get the set of properties for `thing="watermelon"`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(key) FROM Properties WHERE thing='watermelon';
```

Get the most recent value of `key="color"` for `thing="watermelon"`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Properties
WHERE thing='watermelon'
  AND key='color'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But I can't figure out how to combine the two. I'm probably coming at this from an imperative programming perspective, which is why I'd appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 4):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can simply use MAX() to select one row from a group:

```
SELECT key, value, MAX(timestamp)
FROM Properties
WHERE thing = 'watermelon'
GROUP BY key;
```

Comment: How does SQLite know to pick the `value` that corresponds to the max timestamp? What if the query was `select key, value, max(timestamp), min(timestamp)`, which `value` would the query return then?

Comment: Then it randomly picks one of those two rows.

Comment: wouldn't it still pick a random `value` row in your query? I'm not sure about SQLite but this is a common mistake in MySQL because according to the MySQL documentation the engine is permitted to return a random value when selecting a column not in the group by but in practice it often returns the one associated with the max/min etc, so people assume that's how it works. But the behaviour could change version by version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752556/is-it-safe-to-include-extra-columns-in-the-select-list-of-a-sqlite-group-by-quer

Comment: SQLite guarantees that the other columns' values come from a row that matches a MIN()/MAX().

Comment: [From the official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, it is evaluated against a single **arbitrarily** chosen row from within the group.

Comment: When there is MIN()/MAX(), the choice [is not arbitrary](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html).

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking the query found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089284/how-can-i-select-the-most-recent-input-for-each-member), I've come up with the following:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Properties AS a 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT key, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp 
  FROM Properties 
  WHERE thing='watermelon' 
  GROUP BY key) b 
ON a.key = b.key AND a.timestamp = b.max_timestamp 
WHERE thing='watermelon';
```

Seems to work, though I'd be interested in comments the pros/cons of this query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` for simple and readable solution:

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0da72/6/0)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Properties
WHERE thing = "watermelon"
GROUP BY thing, key
HAVING timestamp = MAX(timestamp)
```

Comment: Any particular reason for downvote? If this solution is somehow wrong I will be happy to hear it.